# Formatting ISO 8601 time into Laravel view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, time, momentjs

I'am working on the Halo 5 API, and I'am pulling time played for each player in a match. So when I pulled my time played for last match, I got this.

> PT8M10.9525157S

I have read that I can use the momentJS library

So I used it to pares my time played like this:

```
<script src="{{  URL::asset('/src/public/js/plugins/moment.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{  URL::asset('/src/public/js/plugins/jquery.js') }}"></script>


    <script>
        var played = moment.duration('{{ $ArenaLastGameTimePlayed }}'); //PT8M10.9525157S
        //console.log(played);
        $("#time").append( "<b>" + played + "</b>");
    </script>
```

When I console.log it, I get this, which seems correct:
[image: My time played in a match]

But when I append it to my #time id inside my div, I get the following result:

> 490952.5157

How can I make it into something like this maybe:  (Hour, Minutes, Seconds)

/**************** Answer *********************/

Thanks to the answer below, this is how I did it.

```
 <script>
        //var string = played.humanize();
        //var string = played.hours() + ' hours, ' + played.minutes() + ' minutes' + played.seconds() + ' seconds';
        var played = moment.duration('{{ $ArenaLastGameTimePlayed }}'); //PT8M10.9525157S
        $("#time").append( "Lasted: " + played.minutes() + ':' + played.seconds() + ' minutes');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the momentjs `humanize()` function that will output a value like `a minute`. Here is how you can use it:

```
var string = played.humanize();
```

But you can also display Hours, minutes and seconds to format it as you like using the `seconds()`, `minutes()` and `hours()` methods:

```
var string = played.hours() + ' hours, ' + played.minutes() + ' minutes' + played.seconds() + ' seconds';
```

So your complete code using one of those would be:

```
<script>
    var played = moment.duration('{{ $ArenaLastGameTimePlayed }}'); //PT8M10.9525157S
    //console.log(played);
    $("#time").append( "<b>" + played.humanize() + "</b>");
</script>
```

Here is more documentation for which methods you can use for durations in momentjs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

I hope this helps!